# Why isn't paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished called after resuming an interrupred IAP restore?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My restore implementation appears to be basically working.

From `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` I block the UI with a modal activity indicator, fire off requests to our server for each restored transaction, get responses back telling me the id of the respective (non-consumable) item to be downloaded. I close the transaction. Finally,  `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` or `restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:` is my cue to remove the activity indicator and if nec. to start downloading. So far so good. It works.

If the restore process is interrupted (app exits), `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` is still doing it's job fine when the app is started up again but I'm not getting the `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` event. Thus, I'm missing the cue to remove the activity indicator and start downloading.

Anybody know what could be causing this?

My workaround is to ignore `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` altogether and instead use `paymentQueue:removedTransactions:` to track the number of items in the queue, act ing accordingly when no more items. Doesn't strike me as particularly elegant, although does open up the option of displaying a more informative progress message.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. I was already using paymentQueue:removedTransactions: for a progress bar update, but I was hoping to use the paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished to close my modal dialog... guess I'll just have to do it the ugly way =/